# Convert Autograd ArrayBox to BigFloat

Tags: scipy, autograd, bigfloat

As said in the title, I want to convert from Autograd ArrayBox to BigFloat.

My function is simple:

```
def fun(mean, variance, bin_mean, bin_variance):

    first = np.float(bf.sqrt(1.0 * bin_variance / (bin_variance + variance)))

    second_numerator = (bin_mean - mean)**2
    second_denominator = 2*(bin_variance + variance)
    second = np.float(bf.exp(-second_numerator/second_denominator))

    return first * second
```

and I need high precision and hence I want to use [bigfloat](https://pypi.org/project/bigfloat/) package. Now, this function is part of a more complex one for which I'm using `scipy.optimize.minimize` function for finding the minimum of the function while also using `autograd` to approximate Jacobian and Hessian matrices. 
The error I'm getting when I run my code is

```
TypeError: Unable to convert argument Autograd ArrayBox with value 0.01297563222656762 of type <class 'autograd.numpy.numpy_boxes.ArrayBox'> to BigFloat
```

So my question is: how to convert from Autograd's ArrayBox to BigFloat? How to even properly extract the value inside the ArrayBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did:

myvariable._value

and I got an array with the values inside the ArrayBox, which then I could manipulate.

I figured it out after checking the  attributes of the ArrayBox using call(myvariable). Looks it is not documented anywhere. 
Hope it helps